# passing parcels between service and activity

Tags: android

Should I worry about battery/cpu consumption when passing lots of data between service and activity ? 
Lets say I can work harder to avoid unnecessary message passing, by holding a reference to data instead of asking the service to broadcast it again, is it a better practice ?
I really need the app to be battery friendly.

Comment: What can I do, or what method can I use to pass data from a `Service` to an `Activity` continually(not continually, but the frequency is high, and it is triggered by a event, like `FileObserver`), thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I can't speak to the exact battery consumption that takes place when broadcasting an intent with a parcelable extra, but I don't think you should be worrying about battery consumption. If your service is processing/updating stateful data that and the activities in question need those updated values then sending broadcasts is the way to go. If the data isn't changing, then there's no need to constantly broadcast it, that would just be a waste of battery. The more major drain on battery is likely going to be whatever expensive operations are taking place inside of your service. Look to optimize the work in the service more than anything, e.g. only update what needs to be updated and try to minimize very battery heavy operations like network calls where possible.